# Premature end of training in TF OD 2 API

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api, roboflow

I've been playing with the Tensorflow Object Detection API 2(TF OD 2) in these days, I'm using the git head  commit [ce3b7227](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/ce3b7227decc947f701168e6f85f551a2ac881f3). My aim is to find the most suitable model for my custom dataset, by using the existent DL Architecture present in theTensorFlow 2 Model Zoo. I've generated my TF Records with the following tutorial of [Roboflow](https://blog.roboflow.ai/how-to-create-to-a-tfrecord-file-for-computer-vision/) and I have been training it with my Laptop and Google Colab, in GPU Mode.

I've found this amazing [Roboflow's Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sLqFKVV94wm-lglFq_0kGo2ciM0kecWD?usp=sharing), while I've tried to reproduce the same steps with my dataset, by using the **models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py**, unluckly for me, the training script always ends before it started to iterate. It didn't show any Python Error and also it show some warnings as usual. The complete output is in my [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LxI9Ix5kuvL71kDJZPwApSFsi1scJvDT?usp=sharing)

I'm fine-tuning the model with the following commands.

```
 PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH=models/ssd_resnet152_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/pipeline.config; MODEL_DIR=training/; NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=10000; SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES=1;

 python models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=$MODEL_DIR --num_train_steps=$NUM_TRAIN_STEPS --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=$SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES --pipeline_config_path=$PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH --alsologtostderr
```

This is my pipeline.config file

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 90
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 640
        width: 640
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_resnet152_v1_fpn_keras"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00039999998989515007
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.029999999329447746
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.996999979019165
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00039999998989515007
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.996999979019165
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          }
        }
        depth: 256
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.6000000238418579
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: false
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 8
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.03999999910593033
          total_steps: 25000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.013333000242710114
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "models/ssd_resnet152_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 25000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "classification"
  use_bfloat16: true
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "datasets/UrbanTracker/urban_tracker_label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "datasets/UrbanTracker/urban_tracker_train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "datasets/UrbanTracker/urban_tracker_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "datasets/UrbanTracker/urban_tracker_test.record"
  }
}
```

And this is how my model's directory looks like.

```
.
├── datasets
│   ├── raccoon
│   │   ├── raccoon_label_map.pbtxt
│   │   ├── raccoon_test.record
│   │   └── raccoon_train.record
│   ├── readme.md
│   └── UrbanTracker
│       ├── labels_urbantracker.txt
│       ├── urban_tracker_label_map.pbtxt
│       ├── urban_tracker_test.record
│       └── urban_tracker_train.record
├── __main__.py
├── models
│   ├── AUTHORS
│   ├── efficientdet_d1_coco17_tpu-32
│   │   ├── checkpoint
│   │   │   ├── checkpoint
│   │   │   ├── ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001
│   │   │   └── ckpt-0.index
│   │   ├── pipeline.config
│   │   ├── saved_model
│   │   │   ├── assets
│   │   │   ├── saved_model.pb
│   │   │   └── variables
│   │   │       ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
│   │   │       └── variables.index
│   ├── faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_640x640_coco17_tpu-8
│   │   ├── checkpoint
│   │   │   ├── checkpoint
│   │   │   ├── ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001
│   │   │   └── ckpt-0.index
│   │   ├── pipeline.config
│   │   ├── saved_model
│   │   │   ├── saved_model.pb
│   │   │   └── variables
│   │   │       ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
│   │   │       └── variables.index
│   └── ssd_resnet152_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8
│       ├── checkpoint
│       │   ├── checkpoint
│       │   ├── ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001
│       │   └── ckpt-0.index
│       ├── pipeline.config
│       ├── saved_model
│       │   ├── assets
│       │   ├── saved_model.pb
│       │   └── variables
│       │       ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
│       │       └── variables.index
├── tools
│   ├── parse_polytrack.py
│   ├── polytrack_csv_to_tfrecord.py
│   ├── raccoon_labels_test.csv
│   ├── raccoon_labels_train.csv
│   ├── split_dataset.py
│   ├── urban_tracker_test.csv
│   └── urban_tracker_train.csv
```

I've converted my Dataset to TFRecord with the TF v1 and v2 API. Also, I've been playing with different training parameters without luck. To check my dataset, in case I've generated it wrongly, I tried with another dataset, the basic [Raccoon Dataset](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset) but I got the same result.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: For models such as *efficientdet_d1_coco17_tpu-32* just change in the *pipeline.config* the parameter   from `fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "classification"` to   `fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"`, check [TF Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8892)